# Permanently run stable diffusion on Google Colab without reinstall?

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I am running stable diffusion on Colab, after I close it down, it takes a long time to re-initialize and re-install the next time I run it. Is there any possible ways to go around it?